# Почему утекает память в Parallel.ForEach

Tags: delphi, foreach, omnithreadlibrary

Я разбираюсь с библиотекой `OmniThreadLibrary`. У нее есть метод для параллельного `For: ForEach`. Я разрабатываю нагруженную систему и мне нужно параллельно обрабатывать некий массив элементов, но при попытке реализации встала проблема утечки памяти.

Вот простой пример:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  loop: IOmniParallelLoop<Integer>;
begin
  while True do
    begin
      loop := Parallel.ForEach(1, 100);
      loop.OnStop(procedure (const task: IOmnitask)
        begin
           loop := nil;
        end);
      loop.Execute(procedure (const i: Integer)
        begin

        end);
     Sleep(100);
   end;
end;
```

При запуске этого кода явно видно, что постоянно растет виртуальная память.

Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так?

Comment: Как то странно что вы внутри уничтожаете loop. Но как вариант можете  воспользоваться FastMM или EurekaLog - они должны помочь отследить в каких именно местах происходит утечка.

Comment: Я пользовался FastMM. но так как он выводит результаты после завершения программы, утечек нет. т.е. при выходе все уничтожается, но во время работы он что то постоянно создает.

Comment: Я считаю, что рост памяти - это нормально и правильно. Ввиду того, что Foreach выполняется в доп. потоке, эти потоки Вы создаете постоянно в цикле, а освобождаться они будут "потом", после того, как отработают, у Вас естественно наблюдается постоянный рост потребления ресурсов. Т.е. количество создаваемых потоков превалирует над самовысвобождаемыми. Sleep не гарантирует начало выполнения нового потока - решение о его запуске принимается только и исключительно планировщиком потоков.